# How to delete record in message box when I uncheck checkbox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, checkbox, messagebox

I'm really newbie in programming. I have  a problem with this source. It must be delete when i uncheck the checkbox. But it still in there. Any solution? Sorry for bad english. :D

```
Public Class Form1
Dim message As String
Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.Enter

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.CheckState = 1 Then
        message = message & CheckBox1.Text & vbNewLine
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox2.CheckState = 1 Then
        message = message & CheckBox2.Text & vbNewLine
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox3.CheckState = 1 Then
        message = message & CheckBox3.Text & vbNewLine
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox(message)
End Sub
```

Comment: "**the**" checkbox?  you show 3.  `message` is always appended to conditionally, so previous selections are retained.  Rather than build it in CheckChanged, build it in ButtonClick so you know the user is done and the states are "final"

Comment: What do you mean by '_it must be delete when i uncheck the checkbox_'? Do you mean the message string must be cleared? Do you mean the checkbox that was unchecked must be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those CheckedChanged events since you are trying to create a string of checked items.  Simply use a StringBuilder to build the string for you when you need it:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                         Handles Button1.Click
  Dim message As New StringBuilder
  If CheckBox1.Checked Then
    message.AppendLine(CheckBox1.Text)
  End If
  If CheckBox2.Checked Then
    message.AppendLine(CheckBox2.Text)
  End If
  If CheckBox3.Checked Then
    message.AppendLine(CheckBox3.Text)
  End If
  MessageBox.Show(message.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: You can just do MsgBox(message)

Comment: @nfell2009 No, you can't.  I made it a StringBuilder.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that part xD